# How to remove cloning in HTML()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the following code. When I click the **"klik small"**, it looks fine, even if I click a few times. The answer remains the same. With results like the following

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="E">TEST</div>
</div>
```

But, If I click the **"klik large"** button, the first click seems fine. However, if the same click more than once, will make more clones like this

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">
                <div class="B">
                    <div class="C">
                        <div class="D">
                            <div class="B">
                                <div class="C">
                                    <div class="D">
                                        <div class="E">TEST</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I stop it like when I first clicked, and if I click on it a few times, the result remains the same as the first one?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.small', function(e) {
  var TEXT = $(".A .D").html();
 $('.A').html( TEXT );
});

$(document).on('click', '.large', function(e) {
  var TEXT = $(".A").html();
 $('.A').html( '<div class="B"><div class="C"><div class="D">'+TEXT+'</div></div></div>' );
});
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">
                <div class="E">TEST</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<button class="button small">Klik small</button>
<button class="button large">Klik large</button>
```

**================= UPDATE ================**

Many responded if I was looking for answers to TEXT, but I asked the element

Please check from this http://jsfiddle.net/yzdjme0k/12/
What am I asking? If I resize the `window.width` browser, and if `window.width` > 1024px, it will bring up the code `<div class="scroll-magnet-container"><div class="scroll-magnet-item is-scrolling"><div class="column-container"><div class="column-contents">` to be `<div class="fixed-wrapper"><div class="scroll-magnet-container"><div class="scroll-magnet-item is-scrolling"><div class="column-container"><div class="column-contents"><div class="content">..... blah blah blah`

But if `window.width` size under < 1024px. the above code will removed. to be `<div class="fixed-wrapper"><div class="content">..... blah blah blah`

However, because I use `resize` function. then any `1px` width that increases in `window.width` will activate the function `html()`

Or u can see  snippet bottom

```js
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    if ($(window).outerWidth() > 1024) {
        $('.fixed-wrapper').html('<div class="scroll-magnet-container"><div class="scroll-magnet-item is-scrolling"><div class="column-container"><div class="column-contents"><div class="content">'+$(".fixed-wrapper .content").html()+'</div></div></div></div>');
    } else  {
        $('.fixed-wrapper').html($(".fixed-wrapper .column-contents").html());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-magnet-container" style="height: 5412px;">
        <div class="scroll-magnet-item is-bottomed" style="width: 326.438px; top: auto;">
            <div class="column-container">
                <div class="column-contents">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="description display-block-smartphone-portrait">
                            <div>
                                <a class="view-product-details-smartphone toggle-details-mobile view" style="">View Details</a>
                                <a class="view-product-details-smartphone toggle-details-mobile close" style="display: none;">Hide Details</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product-details-smartphone" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="vspace1 product-description-text">
                                    <div><span>181349M223006</span></div>
                                    <div><span>Distressed supple leather loafers in white. Round toe. Pull-loop at heel collar. Leather and rubber sole in tan and grey. Tonal stitching.</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="span16 price-container hidden-smartphone-landscape-price">
                                <h3 class="price">
                                    <span class="price sale">$590 USD</span>
                                    <span class="price"> $277 USD</span>
                                </h3>
                                <meta itemprop="price" content="277">
                                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span16 promotions-container">
                                <div data-v-1dd5763a="">
                                    <div class="vspace2 display-block-smartphone-portrait"></div>
                                    <p>You save 53%</p>
                                    <div>
                                        <p class="promotions-container shipping-note"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="vspace1 display-block-smartphone-portrait"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-to-bag-form">
                            <div class="span16">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="vspace1">
                                        <div class="">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn-show-chart">
            View Size Chart
          </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="position: relative;">
                                        <select id="size" name="size" class="vspace2">
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="SELECT A SIZE">SELECT A SIZE</option>
                                     <option value="39_181349M22300601">
          IT 39 - Only one left
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="39.5_181349M22300602">
          IT 39.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option value="40_181349M22300603">
          IT 40 - Only one left
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="40.5_181349M22300604">
          IT 40.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option value="41_181349M22300605">
          IT 41 - Two items left
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="41.5_181349M22300606">
          IT 41.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option value="42_181349M22300607">
          IT 42
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="42.5_181349M22300608">
          IT 42.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="43_181349M22300609">
          IT 43 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="43.5_181349M22300610">
          IT 43.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="44_181349M22300611">
          IT 44 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="44.5_181349M22300612">
          IT 44.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option value="45_181349M22300613">
          IT 45 - Only one left
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="45.5_181349M22300614">
          IT 45.5 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                     <option disabled="disabled" value="46_181349M22300615">
          IT 46 - Sold Out
        </option>
                                    </select>
                                        <!---->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <form type="post" id="addBagForm">
                                <div class="span16 vspace1">
                                    <div data-v-f4bdd476="">
                                        <div id="pdp-bag-captcha" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="button full-width btn-add-to-bag button no-border button-primary">
                                    <span class="button-label">Add to bag</span>
                                    <span class="load-wrapper" style="display: none;">
                                     <span class="load-animation">
                                      <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 12px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0s infinite;"></span>
                                      <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 12px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0.075s infinite;"></span>
                                      <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 0px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0.15s infinite;"></span>
                                     </span>
                                    </span>
                                   </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!---->
                            <div>
                                <form type="post">
                                    <div class="span16 vspace1">
                                        <div>
                                            <div id="pdp-wishlist-captcha" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button no-border heart-icon">
                                     <span class="button-label">Add to wishlist</span>
                                     <span class="load-wrapper" style="display: none;">
                                      <span class="load-animation">
                                       <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 12px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0s infinite;"></span>
                                       <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 12px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0.075s infinite;"></span>
                                       <span class="dot" style="width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 3px; margin-right: 0px; animation: blink 0.45s step-end 0.15s infinite;"></span>
                                      </span>
                                     </span>
                                    </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue , please explain what final result you needed ?

Comment: see my update...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the end result should look like but I can help you showing you what's causing your problem.

`var TEXT = $(".A").html();` in this line you get the html of every Element with the class A. You don't get the TEXT Content but the full html content, this will be `<div class='[...]` So now your text variable already has two divs. In the next line you create two more divs and then append the content of TEXT to it. Meaning you duplicate your div elements.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `$(".A").html();` to  `$(".A").text();` on Klik large click because you are selecting all the html object of `.A` selector. [`$(".A").text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.small', function(e) {
    var TEXT = $(".A .D").html();
    $('.A').html(TEXT);
});

$(document).on('click', '.large', function(e) {
    var TEXT = $(".A").text().trim();
    $('.A').html(`<div class="B">
 <div class="C">
 <div class="D">
 ${TEXT}
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
 <div class="B">
  <div class="C">
   <div class="D">
    <div class="E">TEST</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<button class="button small">Klik small</button>
<button class="button large">Klik large</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**------------------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------------------**

You can do this in 2 ways. You can detect what the child element of .fixed-wrapper is before activating the .html or you can use a variable to check if the width of the window already resized to below 1024 or above 1024 once

An example would be the following:

```js
var isLayout1024 = false;
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    if ($(window).outerWidth() > 1024 && !isLayout1024) {
     isLayout1024 = true;
        $('.fixed-wrapper').html('<div class="scroll-magnet-container"><div class="scroll-magnet-item is-scrolling"><div class="column-container"><div class="column-contents"><div class="content">'+$(".fixed-wrapper .content").html()+'</div></div></div></div>');
    } else if($(window).outerWidth() <= 1024 && isLayout1024)  {
     isLayout1024 = false
        $('.fixed-wrapper').html($(".fixed-wrapper .column-contents").html());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code
use combination of class `.A` and class `.D` to avoid repetition in Klik large
also add class `.E` div if combination not found

```js
$(document).on('click', '.small', function(e) {
  var TEXT = $(".A .D").html();
 $('.A').html( TEXT );
});

$(document).on('click', '.large', function(e) {
  var TEXT = $(".A .D").html() ? $(".A .D").html() : '<div class="E">TEST</div>';
 $('.A').html( '<div class="B"><div class="C"><div class="D">'+TEXT+'</div></div></div>' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
 <div class="B">
  <div class="C">
   <div class="D">
    <div class="E">TEST</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<button class="button small">Klik small</button>
<button class="button large">Klik large</button>
```

Comment: see my update...What if the same uses .resize()? so every 1px. then function in html() will always work?